# Proportion Test on Proportion Data

Tags: proportion

I'm attempting to analyze the results of a game where one player is eliminated each round. I want to try to evaluate whether a player who wins an advantage in the first round of the game (usually one per game) survives more rounds on average than players who did not win an advantage in the first round.

Because the number of total rounds is different for each game, my dependent variable is calculated as percentage of rounds survived. To make the comparison between the "Advantage" group and "No Advantage" group, is it possible to do a proportion test by pooling all "rounds played by someone who won an advantage" together (same for "rounds played by someone who did not win an advantage")? Or am I violating an assumption here because the rounds aren't fully independent (if someone is eliminated, they won't survive any more rounds after that)?

[image]

Comment: Can you post some of the data?  This sounds a lot like a polya urn and you would be interested in seeing if "balls" (here players) are "picked" (here eliminated) later in time.

Comment: Added a picture of example data to the original post, hope this helps!

Comment: Did these players play in the same game together, or did these players play in separate games?

Comment: The players in game_id = 1 all played together, the players in game_id = 2 all played together, and so on.

Comment: I don't think a test of proportions is the right way to do this because the proportions are dependent.  If I am eliminated, then your proportion of rounds survived automatically becomes larger.  I know how I would approach this if all games were the same number of rounds, but I think the varying number of rounds makes things complicated.

Comment: From the data posted, what I can see is the you don't have enough players who had the advantage, to be able to meaningfully test whether there is a difference i. e. One dataset is too small. If your full dataset is larger than this, the number of rounds is irrelevant to your question as stated. You said an advantage in the first round. That's all you should look at, with a considered output to measure progress.